# spark dataframe: how to explode a IntegerType column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, explode

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("id", IntegerType, false),StructField("num", IntegerType, false)))
```

I want to generate continuous number from 0 to num  by every id。
I don't know how to do ..
Thanks

[data and result here !!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVomj.png)

Comment: Added code format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UDF` and `explode` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, explode}

val range = udf((i: Int) => (0 to i).toArray)
df.withColumn("num", explode(range($"num")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `DataFrame.explode`:

```
df.explode(col("id"), col("num")) {case row: Row =>
    val id = row(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
    val num = row(1).asInstanceOf[Int]
    (0 to num).map((id, _))
}
```

Or in RDD land, you can use [`flatmap`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) for this:

```
df.rdd.flatMap(x => (0 to x._2).map((x._1, _)))
```